# How to search in Safari's history on iOS?

Tags: ipad, safari, ios, mobile-safari

In Safari on my iPad, I want to find all the questions I have visited recently on *[Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)*.

I type *apple.st*. Safari suggests me some pages.

In *Bookmarks and history*, Safari gives me at most 5 results.

**How can I have *all the results* ?**

I would like a solution for iOS 7. I am interested in solutions for iOS 8 too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't list entire search results from your history on iOS. The most you can do is as you have done by searching in Spotlight search and using the ~5 search results.

If your Safari history is synchronised with iCloud, you can search the entire history in Safari on OS X. Open Safari and press ⌥⌘2, then use the search box in the bottom-right corner.